# Get pending orders for a specific customer using REST API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am trying to get the pending orders for a specific customer using :

> https://{domain.com}/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=aaa@gmail.com

But I got this error :

> Report ID: webapi-58e37396d92a8; Message: Property "FilterG‌​roups"
>   does not have corresponding setter in class
>   "Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria". in
>   /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

How can I fix it?

**-Another question, This API forces me to use an Admin token. I see it is not security wise. How can I use a customer token ?**

Comment: I want to return the orders for a specific customer. at all I did it. but Is there is a solution for the second question?

Comment: I want to know: This part is working or not: `https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders? searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=stat‌​us& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​‌​=eq`?

Comment: No it is not working,  I meaning for a specific customer. `https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=aaa@google.com&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=pending&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`

Comment: Yes, already i tried this before and is working. do you have any idea about the second part of the question?

Comment: Try to get: `https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders? searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=stat‌​us& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​‌​=eq& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=customer‌​_email& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=aaa@gmai‌​l.com& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]‌​‌​=eq`

Comment: I tried your last one, Not working. the one i sent in third comment is working.

Comment: I got this error from your one: Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-58e3923ca4a22; Message: Property "FilterG‌​roups" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria". in /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[f‌​ilter_groups][0][fil‌​ters][0][field]=cust‌​omer_email&searchCri‌​teria[filter_groups]‌​[0][filters][0][valu‌​e]=aaa@google.com&se‌​archCriteria[filter_‌​groups][0][filters][‌​0][condition_type]=e‌​q&searchCriteria[fil‌​ter_groups][1][filte‌​rs][0][field]=status‌​&searchCriteria[filt‌​er_groups][1][filter‌​s][0][value]=pending‌​&searchCriteria[filt‌​er_groups][1][filter‌​s][0][condition_type‌​]=eq

Answer (score 0):

None of Above works for me unless below one.

```
http://domain.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=pending& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```